# How to calling special condition in some column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

For this query :

```sql
WITH CTE (customerID,FirstWeek,RN) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        customerID, MIN(DATEPART(week, tp_date)) TransWeek,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerID ORDER BY DATEPART(week, tp_date) ASC) 
    FROM 
        all_table
    GROUP BY 
        customerID, DATEPART(week, tp_date)
) 
SELECT 
    CTE.customerID, CTE.FirstWeek,  
    (SELECT TOP 1 (DATEPART(week, c.tp_date))   
     FROM all_table c 
     WHERE c.customerID = CTE.customerID 
       AND DATEPART(week, C.tp_date) > CTE.FirstWeek) SecondWeek 
FROM 
    CTE  
WHERE 
    RN = 1
```

I get this result :

| CustomerID | firstweek | secondweek |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 35 | 37 |
| C002 | 35 | 37 |
| C003 | 35 | 39 |
| C003 | 36 | 37 |

But what to do if I want the result to show only the first week in 35 and second week 37? The result should look like this:

| CustomerID | firstweek | secondweek |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 35 | 37 |
| C002 | 35 | 37 |

Comment: The first CTE doesn't make too much sense. You are grouping by the second expression and then computing the `MAX()` of it. It will always evaluate to the expression itself. Remove the `MAX()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, run a second CTE to apply your filter in final query. Also, you may not need the `ROW_NUMBER` window function:

```sql
WITH agg AS (
    SELECT 
        customerID, 
        MIN(DATEPART(week, tp_date)) AS FirstWeek
    FROM all_table
    GROUP BY 
        customerID
), main AS ( 
    SELECT 
        customerID, 
        FirstWeek,  
        (
           SELECT TOP 1 DATEPART(week, c.tp_date) 
           FROM all_table c 
           WHERE c.customerID = agg.customerID 
             AND DATEPART(week, c.tp_date) > agg.FirstWeek 
        ) AS SecondWeek 
    FROM agg
)

SELECT *
FROM main
WHERE FirstWeek = 35 
  AND SecondWeek = 37
```